# Using varchar variable with IN operator where ints are expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameter-passing

This works:

```
declare @ids varchar(50) = '1, 2, 3'
create table #test  (id int)
exec('insert into #test select userid from users where userid in(' + @ids + ')')
```

This doesn't:

```
declare @ids varchar(50) = '1, 2, 3'
create table #test  (id int)
insert into #test select userid from users where userid in(@ids)
```

It (kinda obviously) returns:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1, 2, 3' to data
>   type int.

Is there an *elegant* way to make the query work without using `exec()`, like I try to do in the second piece of code?

Comment: There are multiple ways, One is to use Dynamic-SQL like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33010765/5070879), or just split string.

Comment: error are coming because `@ids` is nvarcahr and `userid`is integer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591856/assign-a-list-of-integers-to-an-var/2592071#2592071. Is this solution

Comment: This is rather ugly and non-sargable: `WHERE CONCAT(',', REPLACE(@ids, ' ', ''), ',') LIKE concat('%,', userid, ',%') `

Comment: There is no elegant solution at level you are examining the problem. The elegant solution is to step back in your design and not put yourself in this position in the first place. Instead, you want to be able construct a `select` query that describes the values for your `IN()` clause. This means looking at how those lists are first generated, and finding a different way to get that data to sql server.

Comment: If you're staying with a string variable there is no elegant way.  You could split the @ids into a temp table, and join to that table in the select.